# Setting up Xcode project to easily create "sub apps"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've been posed a very specific challenge at work and I haven't been able to come up with a satisfying solution with my own research so I figured I'd ask here in case someone else had a similar experience.

Basically I'm about to start coding an app that serves as some kind of "hub" for events, the user would be able to find the event they're interested in, select it and see the details about it/interact in what would essentially be its own "micro-app".
 
The problem is I also need to be able to easily take the "model" (general UI logic, common resources  and procedure etc.) for this "micro-app" and turn them into a standalone app dedicated to a single event with minimal effort (it needs to be done by a non-coder with the help of some setup instructions so not via actually coding it but not "one click you're done" either).

I tried using sub projects, specifically having a sub project that constitutes the mini app be included inside the "hub"'s project, but I can't figure out how to share resources between the two.
I tried creating a simple test app that loads a UIViewController from the subproject and while I was able to have the parent recognize the headers I was not able to load resources (namely a storyboard).

I'm researching the use a static library (maybe using an Xcode template to simplify the process for a non coder) as I understand it would let me pack resources as well, but it seems like they'd make development harder by "obscuring" what's inside the library (especially if I wanted to work on both the "micro-app" and the "hub" at the same time) so I was wondering if there's a better way that I'm not aware of.

Of course I could just make a template once the code is finalized which would take care of the "easy creation" angle but then I would need to update the template every time something changes.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, Xcode makes this really easy, actually. Create your base app, and add duplicate targets for the other versions.

If you need to differentiate things in shared code, add a compiler flag for each target and then use `#IFDEF`s in your code to differentiate. You can also create different storyboards on a per target basis, or use the same one for every target. It sounds like this won't be necessary for you, though.

To create a target, click on your project in the project navigator in Xcode, then right click on your existing app target (*not* the one with the "Tests" suffix), then choose "Duplicate". From there, you can change the Product Name to be whatever is appropriate for that "mini app".

Then whatever assets that particular mini app uses could be added to the project (presumably in their own group), and added only to the targets to which they are applicable. I'm not sure exactly what all your needs are, but this would be the basic route I would take to make this possible.

Comment: So targets would be a good approach to this then? Right now I was successful in sharing resources via a Static Library that packs a bundle. I got around the "obscurity" problem by adding the library as a subproject and it seems to work well enough, though I'm wary of issues later in development — The thing about these "mini apps" is that they will all be the same so it's not like I need to be able to add new "parts" to the hub app, is more like I need to be able to take the "mini app" and move it to a new standalone project easily, having it act as it would when used via the "hub" app

Comment: Oh, if you need to be able to move it to a new project, a target is definitely not the best way to do it.